# Why does WebKit not even try to build? (WebKit is now built (00m:00s))

Tags: qt, webkit

I've been attempting to build WebKit for Qt with WebGL support. According to https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitWebGL, I need to run the following command to do so:

```
Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --qt --3d-canvas
```

That's exactly what I did. I've downloaded the WebKit source code (r171650) and attempted to compile it with exactly that command - unfortunately, it seems as though the build-webkit script just exits without doing anything:

```
dominik@ubuntu:~/WebKit-r171650$ export QTDIR=/usr/share/qt5/
dominik@ubuntu:~/WebKit-r171650$ Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --clean
dominik@ubuntu:~/WebKit-r171650$ Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --qt --3d-canvas

====================================================================
 WebKit is now built (00m:00s). 
====================================================================
dominik@ubuntu:~/WebKit-r171650$
```

Any ideas about why this might be happening?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is should be asked on the [WebKit mailing list](https://lists.webkit.org/mailman/listinfo)

Comment: Did you try a release tag that is known to build and work ?

Comment: I was using the source code of a nightly build. I'll try a different version and edit my comment if it works.

EDIT: I've tried the version they say to download at https://www.webkit.org/building/checkout.html and I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying build type, this works for me:

```
./Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --debug --efl
```